# Rendering video control with Glass mapper and Experience Editor support

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

[image]

Hi,

I am trying to render a video using `<video>` tag and it expects a url to video file. Looks very straight forward this way but can anyone suggest how I can provide Experience Editor support using `Glass().Editable()`.
The content editor should be able to select the video file from Media Library and it should load the selected video file in Experience Editor. For Images there is out-of-the-box `RenderImage()`  method available. How to achieve this for rendering video?

Please if anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Parry

Comment: Your video field, is it one field only? or multiple fields for every extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open it into `Experience Editor`, you can add the below piece of code or wrap up your HTML code in Glass Mapper `@using`:

```
@using (Html.Glass().BeginEditFrame(Model, "Edit video field", x => x.VideoFile))
{
    <div style="float:left; padding-right:20px">
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
            <source src="@Model.VideoFile" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="@Model.VideoFile" type="video/ogg" />
            your custom message
        </video>
    </div>
}
```

If you have more than one video field for each extension. Your code will be:

```
@using (Html.Glass().BeginEditFrame(Model, "Edit video fields", x => x.VideoFileA, x => x.VideoFileB))
{
  your HTML
}
```

You don't need to create any custom `Experience Button or Frame` for this.